# Properly working with div heights - vh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an interesting issue revolving around this page. What should happen is you see a nice red box over a video, and inside this box are link buttons that when clicked load some text from an external file, and put it into the one of the sub divs. The text shouldn't overflow the box, and the box should stretch to the bottom of the viewport. The issue is that this works terribly on different devices. If you have a really long chapter, and you're in a smaller browser, you can scroll down, but then you can't scroll back to the top.

I looked into many solutions, as you can see - followed countless Stack Overflow posts, but somehow, I sense that my issue may lie deeper in the css, that somehow I'm doing it wrong. If someone could take a look and maybe help me down the right track for this, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

```
 html, body{
    height: 100%;
 }
 .box{
    background-color: rgba(112, 0 , 0, .85);
    width: 60%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ */
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
#storybox{
    width: 90vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
}
#storyc{
    display: inline-block;
}
.no_box{
    height: 50vh;
}
.link_box{
    height: 100vh;
}
.link_box a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;       
}
.link_box a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;       
}
#storybox a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#storybox a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.link_box ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    line-height: 400%;
}
.box ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    line-height: 400%;
}
.large_text{
    font-size: 24px;
}
.title_text{
    font-size: 48px;
}
.left_align{
    text-align: left;
}
#big-video-wrap{
    z-index: -1;
}

#storybox{
    display: none;
}

#story{
    text-align: left;
}

/* http://sixrevisions.com/css/disable-text-selection/ */
.no-select {
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* KHTML browsers (e.g. Konqueror) */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* Disable Android and iOS callouts*/
 }
```

JS:

```
    function getCookie(cname) { //http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return  c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
//The one and only cookie (we can expand later if need be.)
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!getCookie("landed")){
        window.location.assign("./landing.php");
    }
    $("#links").on('click', 'a', function(){
        $("#storybox").css("display", "none");
        var chapter = $(this).attr("data-chnum");
        $("#chaptertitle").html("Chapter " + chapter);
        $.ajax({
        url: "chapters/ch" + chapter + ".php#story",
        success: function(res){
        $("#links").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#storyc").html(res + "<p><b><a href='#links'>Return</a></b></p>"); 
        $("#storybox").slideDown(800);
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
        },
        statusCode: {
        404: function(){
            $("#storyc").html("<p>Error, chapter not found!</p><p><b><a href='#links'>Return</a></b></p>");
            $("#storybox").slideDown(800);
        }
        },
        async: false,
        });
    return true;
});
    $("#storyc").on('click', 'a', function(){
    $("#links").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#storybox").css("display", "none");
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
    $("#storyc").html("");
    });
});
$(function() {
    var BV = new $.BigVideo();
    BV.init();
    BV.show('https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4',{ambient:true});
});
```

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link href='js/BigVideo/css/bigvideo.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link href='css/styles.css?1457332650' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <script data-rocketsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
     <script data-rocketsrc="js/video-js/video.js" type="text/rocketscript">       </script>
     <script data-rocketsrc="js/BigVideo/lib/bigvideo.js" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
     <script data-rocketsrc="js/application.js?1457332650" type="text/rocketscript"></script>
     <title>----------------</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='no_box'></div>
    <div class='box link_box no-select' id='links'>
        <ul id='linksul'>
            <li class='large_text'>&copy; 2016 -------------</li>
            <li class='large_text'><a href='#storybox' data-chnum='i'>Dedication</a></li>
            <li class='large_text'><a href='#storybox' data-chnum='I'>Chapter I</a></li>
            <li class='large_text'><a href='#storybox' data-chnum='II'>Chapter II</a></li>
            <li class='large_text'><a href='#storybox' data-chnum='III'>Chapter III</a></li>
            <li class='large_text'><a href='#storybox' data-chnum='IV'>Chapter IV</a></li>
            <li class='large_text'><a href='#storybox' data-chnum='V'>Chapter V</a></li>
            <li class='large_text'><a href='#storybox' data-chnum='NEXT'>Next</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
<div class='no_box'></div>
<div id='storybox' class='box'>
    <p class='large_text' id='chaptertitle'>Chapter:</p>
    <div id='storyc'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you create a jsfiddle | plnkr and demonstrate instead of lengthy questions.

Comment: Okay, I'll try and do that. Should I delete this question and repost - I was planning on leaving my computer, and I'd rather not come back to 0 reputation.

Comment: Instead of deleting, edit it... ;)

Comment: Okay, I'll edit it in the morn - thanks for the advice!